# Gamma function (for real z). Confusion to be cleared.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

This question is about the gamma function defined only for $z \in \mathbb{R}, z \gt 0$.

So the definition is as follows

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z-1} \cdot e^{-x}\ dx$$

(again: there are no complex numbers/variables here).

I am reading this integral as if it's improper only at its upper bound (but maybe I am wrong here).

My question is what happens when $z=1$?

Is the integral improper also at its lower bound (the point zero)?

I mean, when $z=1, x=0$ we have $x^{z-1} = 0^0$ which is not really well defined. Right?

Or maybe... when $z=1$, should we just understand/read up-front the integral as being equal to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\ dx$$

I guess the same confusion applies when $0 \lt z \lt 1$

In that case ($z \lt 1$), is the integral improper also at its lower bound (the point zero)?

Maybe I should just (from the very start) read this integral as being improper at both its ends. Is that how I should read it?

Comment: Maybe most straightforward is to interpret it as a Lebesgue integral: Then it doesn't matter that $0^0$ is not well-defined, since the (Lebesgue) integral of a function remains unchanged when that function is altered on a Lebesgue null set, and $\{0\}$ is a Lebesgue null set. You can also see it as an improper Riemann integral as you say. For $0<z<1$, the function that is integrated has a singularity at $x=0$, but it remains improperly and Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Are you thinking of $z=0$?

Comment: @Aruralreader No, for $z=0$, I think the function is not defined. Right? Actually I am not sure what happens with this integral for $z=0$, I was just told $\Gamma(z)$ is not defined for $z=0$. Not sure why.

Comment: @peter.petrov: correct.

Comment: The $\Gamma$-function is defined for complex $z$ with real part purely positive.  When $z$ is real and $0 < z < 1$ it is improper at the lower bound, as you point out (but it converges still).

Comment: @Randall OK. What about for $z=1$? Again, is it improper at the lower bound?

Comment: No, it's just the integral of $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Randall Hm, OK, thanks, I suspected that too. Interesting.

Comment: It's pretty clear that $x^0=1$ at least when $x \neq 0$.  And if you want to argue about what $0^0$ means (some people do) it won't matter because the value of the integral will not be affected by altering a single $y$-coordinate anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is improper in both the lower and upper limits of integration.

The best way to study its convergence is to splite the integral in two:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt + \lim_{\delta \to \infty } \int_{1}^{\delta} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt$$

Note that for $t>0\quad 0<e^{-t}<1$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}$

we have

$$ e^{-t}t^{z-1}<t^{z-1}$$

then if $\epsilon>0$

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt < \int_{\epsilon}^{1} t^{z-1}dt = \frac{1}{z} -\frac{\epsilon^{z}}{z}$$

So if $z>0$
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt < \int_{\epsilon}^{1} t^{z-1}dt < \frac{1}{z} $$
Then
$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt   \leq \frac{1}{z} \quad z>0 $$

Now for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$e^{t}> \frac{t^n}{n!} \Longrightarrow e^{-t}< \frac{n!}{t^n} $$

if $z>0$ we can always find $n\in \mathbb{N}$  such that $n>z+1$ and

$$ \int_{1}^{\delta} e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt < \int_{1}^{\delta} \frac{n!}{t^{n+1-z}} = n!\frac{1-\delta^{z-n}}{n-z} < \frac{n!}{n-z}, $$

Hence

$$  \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt = \lim_{\delta \to \infty}  \int_{1}^{\delta} e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt \leq \frac{n!}{n-z}$$

So both improper integrals exist if $z>0$.

Comment: Nice proof. And I didn't find any flaws btw. I think it works fine. Thank you.